# matlab code analyzer produces empty tooltips

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, ide, tooltip

I'm running MATLAB (R2013b) on Ubuntu (results of `ver` command are pasted below).

I've just started working with this system, and I've realized that coding is seriously hard because the typical "tooltips" that show up in the editor are empty. Unfortunately I cannot paste screenshots, but here I describe the problem: the orange marks on the right margin of the editor should indicate a warning. Passing the cursor on them, one typically gets a tooltip with a short message, detailing the reason of the warning.

In my case, I still see the tooltip... but cannot read anything in there, it's just a gray rectangle. This is terribly annoying... Some idea on what may be the problem?

```
>> ver
MATLAB Version: 8.2.0.701 (R2013b)
Operating System: Linux 3.5.0-41-generic #64~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 12 16:50:04 UTC 2013 x86_64
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot™ 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
```

Comment: I have the same problem! I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, MATLAB R2013b

Comment: see for example: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/116987-empty-tooltips-in-code-analyzer

Comment: and http://askubuntu.com/questions/476306/empty-tooltips-in-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Unity desktop (if you don't know, you probably are, since Unity is the default).

I've encountered your problem with multiple Matlab versions under Linux, and it always boiled down to using a "3D / fancy pants" window manager.

Try using the "Gnome Classic (no effects)", "Ubuntu 2D" or mate sessions and report back whether your problem still exists. Here's a screenshot of the standard desktop login screen in Ubuntu 12.04:

[image]

To see the available sessions, do a left-mouse click on the ubuntu logo next to the username (here test):

[image]

Comment: This is working for me. 

I installed gnome classic through


`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`



But in this way I loose all the advantages of Unity. :( It is a pity.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it without disabling Unity.

Solution:

-open matlab

-go to Preferences->colors

-uncheck "use system colors" for desktop tool colors

-Apply

Now you should see text.

It seems likely that the problem is due to one of 3 scenarios:

1) The relevant default colors in Unity are grey text ion grey background.

2) Matlab Doesn't manage to read the default relevant colors from Unity

3) there is a bug in matlab where it not just greys out the color controls in the GUI but actually greys out the underlying colors.

Comment: Followed these steps, then closed and opened matlab, but still gray tooltips. (Fedora 22 with gnome 3)