# Matlab linux GUI glitches

Tags: linux, matlab, user-interface

I've been having this problem with the Matlab GUI (linux) that has been annoying me for over a year but I still haven't found a solution.

Basically, the autofix hints are not displayed. When I move the mouse cursor over a potential warning/suggestion, a gray-background pop-up appears but the text inside is missing. The same happens when I hover over those little warning bars on the right hand side of the editor. Does anyone have any clue what might be causing this?

Screenshot: http://i58.tinypic.com/4veu.png

This happens only on my linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, NVidia GeForce with nvidia driver).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you really waited a whole year to ask for help here?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling? I have run Matlab on ubuntu before and these things appeared to work.

Comment: @Benoit_11: I hoped I would figure it out eventually ;-)

Comment: @krisdestruction Yes, I had this problem with R2014a and now with R2015a -- no difference.

Comment: @Anton Assuming you have a proper license, why don't you contact their support and see what they say?

Answer (score 2):

For those interested, this issue appears to be related to the Unity Desktop. Mathworks does not provide a fix but suggests using a different XServer instead. Here is the answer I received from support:

> This issue is known to occur due to a windowing system used with
>   "linux" on which MATLAB has not been tested. It has been observed that
>   if you are using "Unity desktop" in "linux", then the tooltips are
>   displayed as blanks.
>
> To work around this issue, you may try switching off "Unity desktop".
>   You can refer to the following links for more information on this
>   issue:
>
> http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/116987-empty-tooltips-in-code-analyzer
>
> [matlab code analyzer produces empty tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915939/matlab-code-analyzer-produces-empty-tooltips)

Indeed, I tried lubuntu and XUbuntu (Xfce) and the tooltips in Matlab were working in both cases. I find Unity very handy because I got used to it, so for now, I will probably simply not use this Matlab feature. Hopefully this will be fixed eventually.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old post but some people may be still looking for a solution or a hack. Well, I also had this issue on R2015a when using two monitors and hiding Ubuntu 14.04 sidebar seems to do the trick. This link explains how to do it: http://www.howtogeek.com/198218/how-to-easily-hide-the-unity-launcher-in-ubuntu-14.04/. Hope it helps!

This is accomplished, in the article, by:-

> 1) Select “System Settings” from the drop-down menu.
>
> 2) The “System Settings” dialog box displays. In the “Personal”
>   section, click “Appearance.”
>
> 3) On the “Appearance” screen, click the “Behavior” tab.
>
> 4) On the right side of the “Behavior” tab, there’s an ON/OFF switch.
>   Click the switch so it reads ON.
>
> 5) The ON/OFF switch also turns orange. Additional options for how to
>   show the hidden Unity Launcher become available in the “Auto-hide the
>   Launcher” section of the “Behavior” tab. Under “Reveal location,”
>   select whether you want to move the mouse to any location on the “Left
>   side” or just to the “Top left corner” of the screen to reveal the
>   Unity Launcher. Use the “Reveal sensitivity” slider to change the
>   sensitivity of the reveal location.
>
> 6) Once you have chosen your settings, close the “Settings” dialog box
>   by clicking the “X” button in the upper-left corner of the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me in Ubuntu 15.10 using xfce, with two monitors connected to an Nvidia GeForce 8600 GT, one of which is rotated to portrait orientation. The "workaround", from [the page Anton linked](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/116987-empty-tooltips-in-code-analyzer), is to resize my matlab desktop such that the red underlined text or red scrollbar annotation is in the bottom third of my left monitor. Unbelievable.

My preferred workaround is to use Python+Scipy+Matplotlib instead of Matlab.

Comment: I'm having this same problem on Ubuntu 15.10 with Gnome 3. Unfortunately, the workaround you posted doesn't work for me, and I have to use matlab all semester for a course. Drat.

edit: Ohh, it works for me in the TOP 1/3 of either monitor.